# Drawable Canvas

Tags: apache-flex, canvas, actionscript, air, flex-spark

I recently upgraded my Flash Builder from Burrito to 4.5 Premium. I am trying to create this ([Drawing Demo](http://www.munkiihouse.com/flexapps/DrawableCanvas/DrawingDemo.html)) in the latest version of Flex, on Blackberry Playbook, but I am getting errors:

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

<s:Panel layout="absolute" title="Draw Test" backgroundColor="#ffffff">
    <mx:Canvas backgroundColor="#ffffff">
    <mh:DrawableCanvas id="main" backgroundColor="#ffff80" backgroundAlpha="0" width="100%" height="100%" y="0" x="0">
    </mh:DrawableCanvas>
    </mx:Canvas>
</s:Panel>

</s:Application>
```

**The Error**

The prefix "mx" for element "mx:Canvas" is not bound. I have tried adding "xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" to the head with no joy.

Is canvas no longer supported? All I want is a canvas to draw onto to capture a human signature...

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Took onboard the advice but still getting something wrong, see screenshot.

[image]

Any ideas? Am I missing a mx.swc or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canvas and all other components are still supported since Flex4 is backwards compatible with Flex3.

In your case, the error message says it all.

Your application does not correctly refer to the mx: namespace.
Therefore, it will not be able to find the Canvas component.

In a Spark application, it is advised to add the mx namespace as follows:

```
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 

instead of 

xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
```

If your are migrating your Flex3 Halo application to a Flex4 Spark application, please read the [official migration guide](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/gumbo/gumbo_featuresmigrate.pdf). Chapter 4 is particularly useful.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks but still getting same issue, check screenshots

Comment: @Phil, you changed FX, not MX.  This is the correct answer.  Also, don't use MX components if you don't have to.

Comment: xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your project can use both MX and Spark components in `Properties -> Flex Build Path`
2. Move caret to the end of `<mx:Canvas` and press `Ctrl + Space`. IDE should suggest correct namespace.

Comment: Thanks but still getting same issue, check screenshots

Comment: Screenshot looks like from an old version of Flash Builder. Please make sure that it's Flash Builder 4.5.